# How can I check if a text box is empty using Katalon Studio (or Selenium)?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, katalon

My site has a text field with a default value that is filled after first user login. But, on the first visit, the text box is empty. 
How can I check if a text box is empty or not? Using Katalon Studio keywords (or Selenium, because I figure it should be the same or similar)?

Comment: Please try and let me know if this works https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25499551/selenium-webdriver-how-to-check-whether-a-text-field-is-blank-i-e-no-input-is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, get the value inside the input box and compare.

```
WebElement A = driver.findElementById("locator");
String text = A.getAttribute("value");
if(text.isEmpty()){
        System.Out.Println("input box is empty");
}
```